# WebGrid ActionLink how to get row object

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid, actionlink

I have WebGrid which is build using Model I build it using code below:

View

```
@model IEnumerable<ExampleMVC4.Models.LicenseInfo>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Licenses";
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model);    
}
<h2>Licenses</h2>
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table table-striped table-hover",
  columns: new[] {
    grid.Column("SerialNumber"),                                   
    grid.Column("Name"),
    grid.Column("Organization"),
    grid.Column("Email"),
    grid.Column("DateActivated"),
    grid.Column(header: "IsValid", format: item=>new HtmlString(Html.ActionLink((string)item.IsValid.ToString(), "Deactivate", new { @id =  item.SerialNumber} ).ToString()))
  })
  <p>@ViewBag.Message</p>
```

Control

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var data = getLicenseInfoList();
    return View(data);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Deactivate(string serialNum_)
{
    if (serialNum_ != null)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = serialNum_;
    }
    return View();
}
```

But I am unable to get it to call `Deactivate()` function with serial number.

What is the proper way to handle `ActionLink` click inside `WebGrid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ActionLink is generating a route parameter named `id` ( `... new { @id =  item.SerialNumber} ..` but you methods parameter name is `serialNum_`. Change the methods signature to

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Deactivate(string id)
```

Note also its a link so its a GET, not a POST (although its not clear what the method does)

Comment: I would like to get serial number in this method and change IsActive to true/false then reload same grid. Right now I am getting error saying that could find view.

Comment: Is the controller method now being called and is the `id` parameter the serial number you are expecting (i.e. does this answer your original question?).

Comment: Note its unclear what your trying to do - all you call is `return View();` which would return a view named `Deactivate` which I suspect your have not created and its probably not what you want to return anyway. You would be far better off just using jquery/ajax to post the serial number, update the database, the return Json indicating success (and update the DOM - eg. change the link text from "Deactivate" to "Activate"), but that the subject of another question.

Comment: Also I think you can simplify you link to `format: (item) => Html.ActionLink(((string)item.IsValid), "Deactivate", new { id = item.SerialNumber })),` - `ActionLink` returns `HtmlString` so no convert it again

Comment: Yes, controller method is called and id has serial number. But I don't want to create another view. Is there anyway to redirect back to Index? Or just reload that page? Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Then you should mark this as accepted and ask a new question. As I noted above, the best way is to use ajax to avoid having to render the view again, but you can always do `RedirectToAction("Index");` rather than `return View();` if performance is not a concern.

Comment: And strictly it is actually a POST since your modifying data, so you should be rendering a `<form>` rather that an `<a>` tag and posting back to the method if you don't want to use ajax.

Comment: Do you mind showing how should deactivate method should look like? Since question was "What is the proper way to handle ActionLink click inside WebGrid?"